# How do I go to a link from dojo code?

Tags: dojo

I'm generating a link in dojo as a string. How would I use dojo to actually go to that link?

For instance:

```
require(["dojo/linkfollowinglibrary"], function(linklibrary){
var string = "http://www.example.com/Search/Here-is-the-searchstring/"
linklibrary.gotolink(string);
});
```

What is the actual linkfollowinglibrary and what is the call in there that represents gotolink? I'm having difficulty searching it for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special in Dojo to do this, because setting `location.href` already accomplishes this in all browsers:

```
location.href = "http://www.example.com/Search/Here-is-the-searchstring/";
```

Dojo doesn't ordinarily invent APIs unless they add convenience, mitigate cross-browser incompatibilities, or both.  In this case, It's Just JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a newbie and I'm very hesitant to do anything outside of dojo for fear it won't work on some obscure browser.

Comment: Do you know a place I can go to get a list of all other 'safe' all-browser javascript calls like this one you just showed to me?

Comment: Mozilla Developer Network is often a good reference, and usually includes browser support tables.  Example for this case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location (see also the interface it links to, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).  caniuse.com is also useful for certain things, more commonly for modern HTML5/CSS3/JS features and APIs.

Comment: I trust those mozilla guys, I noticed that firefox and seamonkey are much stricter than chrome or IE. For instance query("*[data-type='example'") will work fine in chrome or IE without the closing square bracket. Not in mozilla stuff though! Firefox also seems to require javascript functions to be defined before they are called.

Answer (score 0):

My dojo based solution:

```
    require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"], function (on, domConstruct) {
    var searchString = "The contents of the search box";
    var searchUrl = "/Search/" + searchString;
    var searchlink = domConstruct.toDom("<a href="+searchUrl+"/>");
    on.emit(searchlink, "click", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
   });
```